# Not able to configure TFS backup on TFS2013 environment

Tags: backup

We have setup of TFS2013, earlier backup was configure on this server some how backup location does not exist. I would like to change the backup location.

I followed below steps:

a) Started TFS Admin Console.

b) Clicked on Reconfigure Scheduled Backup

c) Modified path and followed steps of wizard.

d) I am stuck on below screen, Verify button is disabled and not able to move on next step:

[image]

Please suggest what am I missing here?

Comment: I have ignored/Unchecked Report DB steps and then it passed through all steps and that solves my problem.

Comment: Still wanted to know why can't I include ReportServer DB with backup of TFS DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot, there is a  Warning mark followed Reporting Key Step.

> If your deployment uses reporting, you will be prompted for a password
>   in order to back up the encryption key for reporting.
>
> The backups will be encrypted using the key for which you are required
>   to provide a password that is **at least 7 characters long and
>   contains one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and one number.**

[image]

This maybe the root cause why the verify button is disabled and not able to move on next step. You must make sure the Confirm Password and Encryption Key Password is the same. And the password is strong enough to follow the requirements. In other words, you must make sure the warning mark disappear in Reporting Key step.

Hope this helps. Official tutorial of [Configure a backup schedule and plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/config-backup-sched-plan?view=azure-devops) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are champ. Your suggestion worked. Issue was with password complexity.